# Descrease debug output level at Xamarin.Android + Visual Studio

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, visual-studio-debugging

Sorry for lame and easy question but I failed to find an answer to it.
Every time I print something to the System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine I have my message tripled:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
```

Output:

```
[0:]
test
[0:] test 
10-22 19:57:13.981 I/mono-stdout( 1026): test
```

I'm stick to System.Diagnostic.Debug because I write messages from both UI part (monodroid) and business logic (PCL)

Is there any way to descrease level of debug noise of Xamarin.Android?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your own little abstraction. We have the same issue in our project, this little Interface helps:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Write(LogLevel level, String tag, String message);
}
```

Then you have your Loggers for each platform, for example:

```
public class AndroidLogger: ILogger
{
    public void Write(LogLevel level, string tag, string message)
    {
        Android.Util.Log.WriteLine(ConvertLogLevel(level), tag, message);
    }
}
```

You inject the logger in the iOS/Android project and you can even create fancy logger like e.g. a nice file-logger for iOS:

```
#if DEBUG
LOG.AddLogger(new TouchFileLogger());
LOG.AddLogger(new ConsoleLogger());
#endif
```

The LOG-class is static and needs not to know about the implementations, thats why it can be easily used in your shared PCL library.

Hope that helps, despite your problem might be solved by now ;-)

Comment: How would the iOS Logger does look like? `System.Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: The simple console-logger looks like this: Debug.WriteLine(level + " " + message);
For a persistent logging in iOS, we save the logs to a file. Have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/brunnurs/e8400a992eb3a6ef5a77

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Android.Util.Log` instead, this greatly decreases it. It also has different levels of logging which you can filter in logcat.

- Info: `Log.Info()`
- Debug: `Log.Debug()`
- Warning: `Log.Warn()`
- Error: `Log.Error()`
- Verbose: `Log.Verbose()`

and additionally a `WriteLine`, which does all of the above:

```
Log.WriteLine()
```

Comment: what if I'm trying to debug PCL library. There is no Log & Anroid classes but it is monodroid execution context.

Comment: In that case I would do some constructor injection with IoC. TinyIoC could work here or if you are using MvvmCross it is built in.